# The config profile could not be found, Error 255 in makefile

Tags: amazon-web-services, makefile, aws-cloudformation

I have a couple of AWS-CLI commands to run, so I tried to use `makefile`. I have multiple AWS profiles configured. I have a profile name given in makefile as a variable and referred the same in the AWS-CLI command inside a target. When I run the target using make CLI, I got the below error but when I run the same command directly on command-line, it works

```
C:\my-aws>make package
aws cloudformation package \
--profile abc \
--template-file template.yaml \
--s3-bucket cfts \
--s3-prefix _temp \
--output-template-file _o.yaml

The config profile (abc) could not be found
make: *** [makefile:12: package] Error 255
```

**makefile**

```
PROFILE = abc

.PHONY: package
package:
    aws cloudformation package \
    --profile $(PROFILE) \
    --template-file template.yaml \
    --s3-bucket cfts \
    --s3-prefix _temp \
    --output-template-file _o.yaml
```

But when I run directly from the command line, it works

```
C:\my-aws>aws cloudformation package --profile abc --template-file template.yaml --s3-bucket cfts --s3-prefix _temp --output-template-file _o.yaml

Successfully packaged artifacts and wrote output template to file _o.yaml.
Execute the following command to deploy the packaged template
aws cloudformation deploy --template-file C:\my-aws\_o.yaml --stack-name <YOUR STACK NAME>
```

Couldn't able to figure out what I am missing.

Comment: Seems strange. Are you absolutely sure that it works when run directly on the command line? Any chance you are running make as a different user (for example administrator)?

Comment: I'm sure it works when running on the command line, I have edit the question for the same

Comment: OK, the symptoms suggest that you are running the two invocations (one on the command line and the other via make) as different users.

Comment: You can see that I still use `--profile abc` in my command line and make as well

Comment: That’s irrelevant. All distinct users have their own distinct credentials folder. A profile of abc that is visible to one user would not be visible to any other user. I don’t know that this is what’s happening in your case, but it fits the symptoms. Are you running both tests as the same OS user, or not?

Comment: I am the only one using my PC, I am running both as the same OS user

Comment: If you list (dir) and print (type) the AWS credentials file in both scenarios, is it the same file with the same content? You should be able to use: `type "%UserProfile%\.aws\credentials"` though you might have to escape the % characters in your makefile. If it's the same in both then re-run the awscli with the `--debug` option to see if it provides any more details that might explain things.

Comment: I figured it out. I am using Windows machine, `.aws` is in `C:\Users\<user>` folder. But when I run `make` the command looks for credentials under `C:\cygwin64\home\<user>`, which is because I installed make using Cygwin. Your directions helped me resolve this, thanks anyways